# How to prefix html code for clipboard.setText

Tags: .net

well trying to include in clipboard doesn't allowed in below code

```
 if (o["status"].ToString() == "200")
                {
                    TaskbarIcon tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("notifyIcon");
                    tb.ShowBalloonTip("Upload Successful!", Screenshot.Properties.Resources.IMGURL + o["filename"].ToString(), BalloonIcon.Info);

                    Clipboard.SetText(Screenshot.Properties.Resources.IMGURL + o["filename"].ToString());

                }
```

below code need to pass

```
Clipboard.SetText("<img src="Screenshot.Properties.Resources.IMGURL + o["filename"].ToString()\">");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clipboard.SetText("<img src=\""+Screenshot.Properties.Resources.IMGURL + o["filename"].ToString()+"\">");
```

Comment: Hi, please expand on *why* this code answers the question. Code snippets without context are not considered good answers.